# Algorithm Design: Best Way to Represent a 2D Grid, with Boundary Digits, in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, 2d

I like working on algorithms in my spare time to improve my algorithm design skills. I tackle Jane Street's monthly puzzles as my 'monthly challenge'. I've previously developed [algorithms](https://github.com/Tzadiko/JaneStreetPuzzles/blob/master/October%202019/TriTriAgainAgain.cpp) to solve their [October](https://www.janestreet.com/puzzles/tri-tri-again-again/) Puzzle, and have solved their November puzzle by hand.

I solved their [November](https://www.janestreet.com/puzzles/current-puzzle/) puzzle (Hooks #6) by hand, but only because I'm not sure how to solve it (and future puzzles) that involve a grid **with a numbered border**, computationally. I'm not sure how I'd go about setting the foundation this type of problem.

For instance, many of their problems involve a 2D grid with numbers on the border of the grid. Furthermore, a recurring theme is that whatever is in the grid must meet multiple conditions that involve looking at that number from different sides of the grid. For example, if I have the following 2 by 2 grid, with 4 numbers outside its boundaries,

```
  _ _
5|   | 45
5|_ _| 15

Place four numbers in the grid such that, when you
 look at the grid from the left, at least one number
 in that row is the border number.

In the case of the top left of the 2 by 2 grid, 
looking at it from the left means the number 5 must be in either (0,0) or (0,1).

In addition, when looking at that row from the right, the product 
of the numbers in the row must equal the boundary number on the right.

In the case of the top right of the 2 by 2 grid, 
looking at it from the right means the number 9 must be in either (0,0)
 or (0,1), as 9 * 5 = 45.

Hence, the first row in the 2 by 2 grid can either be 5 and 9, or 9 and 5.
```

One of the solutions for this problem, by hand, is

```
(0,0) = 5, (0,1) = 9, (1,0) = 5, (1,1) = 3
```

but how can I go about this computationally?

How can I go about translating these grid-like problems with differing conditions based on the position one "looks" at the grid into code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not convinced these puzzles were meant to be solved via code. They seem idiosyncratic and complicated enough that coding them would be time-consuming.

That said, the November puzzle in particular seems to have rather limited options for "fixing" a number placement. I would consider a backtracking algorithm that keeps a complete board state and has ready methods that evaluate if a particular row or column is not breaking a rule, as well as the "free square" rule.

Then try each possible placement of the numbers given by the black indicators, ordered -- there aren't that many, considering they concatenate squares -- and call the evaluation on the affected rows and columns. Given the constraints, I think wrong branches would likely terminate quickly.

It seems to me it's more or less the best we can do since there don't seem to be clear heuristics to indicate a branch is more likely to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a data structure to represent one filled grid, I would recommend a `struct row` containing numbers `left` and `right` and a `std::vector` of numbers. A grid would be a vector of `row`s. You can write methods that allow you to pass it functions that check conditions on the rows.

But solving these problems in a generic way seems complicated to me. Different rules can mean very different approaches to solving them. Of course, if the instances are always this small, one can probably just try all (reasonable) possible fillings of the grid. But this will very fast become infeasible.

You can maybe implement somewhat generic algorithms, if there are rules that are similar to each other. For example a fixed value for the sum of all numbers in a row is a very similar problem to having a fixed value for the product.

But without constraining the possible rules and finding some similarities in them, you will have to write specific solver code for each and every rule.